# Replace "add an app image"

Tags: site, app

Is there any way I can replace "add an app" image from SharePoint 2013 with my own image? See the image below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just did this and I am able to replace

```
.ms-vl-appadd-img  {
     display:none !important;

}

ms-vl-appimage {
     background: url('/Style Library/Images/spcommon2.png');
     background-position-y : 15%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to Replace the images in sharepoint. To change the icons that are displayed you need to do some css magic. First hide the original images and assign a new background-image to the parent element.

You can refer the following links:

[how to change the image of Share/Follow icons in SP2013 page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/86207/how-to-change-the-image-of-share-follow-icons-in-sp2013-page)

[How to change the SharePoint 2013 logo image dynamically?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/93929/how-to-change-the-sharepoint-2013-logo-image-dynamically)